# My domain return error for texture load image url

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

**image does not load by my domain**

Other domain no problem. it is working

it just doesn't load my domain

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
textureLoader.crossOrigin = '';
var map = textureLoader.load('https://MY-DOMAIN.com/upload/01.png');
```

> Error **:** *GET https://MY-DOMAIN.com/upload/01.png net::ERR_FAILED*
>
> **Note : I'm working on localhost. I taking pictures from remote server**

Comment: Seems like a problem with the SSL certificate of the server.

Comment: I suspected for the certificate but could not find anything. my server can also be the problem?

Comment: I just can see what my browser tells me - if my-domain.com is your domain it says 'invalid certificate'.

Comment: I haven't shared my domain. i wrote a sample domain. my domain does not have ssl problem

Comment: Well what's the actual url to the image you're trying to load?

Comment: I have no problem when I take the same picture from the local directory

Comment: I've tried other domains. In fact, most URLs give the same error. Something prevents you from taking the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the response header your server sends I can see that it doesn't return a **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header. This should either be `<origin>`or `*`.
So I'm afraid you might have to configure your server properly.

I noticed you you're using LiteSpeed Web Server so have a look at their Wiki page: https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:config:cors

If I try to serve your image via a proxy everything's fine.

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
textureLoader.crossOrigin = '';
var map = textureLoader.load('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=https://zomisoft.com/blog_img/5-5bcf0cae447c36.35706243.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Other solution i found**

Get base64 type picture with web service

> Web service

```
<?php

header("access-control-allow-origin: *");


if($_GET['key']=='1453'){
    try {
$path  = $_GET['url'];

$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

    echo $base64;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}else{
    echo 404;
}
```

> three.js

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = data;//base64 type image from web service

var texture = new THREE.Texture();
texture.image = image;

image.onload = function() {
  texture.needsUpdate = true;
};

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  map: texture,
});
```